# About Setting Shortcut keys in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently, I have set the Shortcut keys(Eclipse key) in Android Studio by using below way :

File >> Settings >> Keymap >> Eclipse.

Now, When I press ctrl + space while working with android xml file or java file, it opens Documentation window.

**How can I avoid it ?**

Another problem is that some shortcuts like **ctrl + k** and **ctrl + shift + o**  is also not working. Is there any way to set it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Avoid opening documentation window :

For ubuntu 14.04 : File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion

And unticking **Autopopup Documentation** will hide the documentation window.